# What may cause huge delay when upgrading to beta 16 from beta 15?

Tags: angular, zonejs

I was writing app in beta 15, and now it has come time to upgrade to latest version. I've realized that when I've updated from `beta 15` to `beta 16` (also updating ZoneJS from `0.6.10` to `0.6.12`), my app is freezing the whole browser. I've investigated, and found out that this is caused by large object that I present on front - an array of 1500 objects (presented in simple table).  However, I never had this issue in `<beta15`. Is there anything that has changed, that maybe I've didn't realized?

The only thing I've found was :

> Change detection order changed:
>
> 1. dirty check component inputs
> 2. dirty check content children
> 3. update render nodes

However, the table that I am using, only shows objects, so this shouldn't have an impact on that..

Comment: Why are you only going to beta.16 and not to RC.1? MANY things have changed in RC.1 and it will probably be much easier to just go all the way..

Comment: I am doing step by step update, to RC. I prefer doing this that way, so that I can find bugs like that, and fix them when they occur